# How can I improve write streaming in a text file in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an piece of code in `Python 2.7` that write in a text file named file.txt all possible sequences i j  k l .
My script ran succesfully, but number of written lines in file.txt  is 2401890 and not 2678400=60*24*60*31 lines or sequences.

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(0,59):
        for j in range (0,23):
            for k in range(0,59):
                for l in range(1,31):
                    f.write('%s %s %s %s\n'% (i,j,k,l))
```

Can you tell me a good solution for writing large data in a file text in Python,?
Or, Can you tell me how can I improve read and write streaming in Python ?

Thanks to all!!!

Comment: `l` is `range(1, 31)`, is that correct

Comment: range(0, 59) => [0...58], it should be range(0, 60) => [0...59], etc. From [start] to [end - 1], or simply range(60)

Comment: @qwr , all ranges are defined correctly, because is defined in my requirements

Answer (score 0):

`range` does not include the upper bound, so you need to increment those. Also consider replacing nested for loops with a cleaner version using `itertools.product`.

```
from itertools import product

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    [f.write('%s %s %s %s\n' % t) for t in product(
        range(60), range(24), range(60), range(1, 32))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `list-comprehencion`,

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
         [f.write('%s %s %s %s\n'%(i ,j, k,l)) 
            for i in range(0,59) for j in range(0,23) 
              for k in range(0,59) 
                for l in range(1,31)]
```

Run your script at the `command-line` instead of running it from `IDE`